# WPF text box string format to ignore decimal

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I'm not sure exactly how to write the title for this question, let me dive into it to make it clear...

I have a textbox in a WPF application.  This textbox has two way binding to a property in the class - an integer.  This integer represents a currency amount multiplied by 100 - e.g. $100.00 --> 10000 in integer value.

I'm looking for a format that might allow the user to enter the value of the amount into the textbox with decimals and have that value wind up stored as the integer in the way I've described above.  It should also display any value with the decimal added in the appropriate position.

e.g. user enters $22.31 and integer becomes 2231, value 54598 becomes $545.98 when displayed to the user.

Any ideas on how I can set this up?  What I have right now in the binding is the currency string format, but that isn't quite doing it for me.

```
<TextBox
    Name"TotalAmountLabel"
    Text="Binding Path=TotalAmount, StringFormat=C, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And the underlying property:

```
Private _TotalAmount As Integer
Public Property TotalAmount() As Integer
    Get
        Return _TotalAmount
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _TotalApprovalAmount = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Any ideas?  I know I might have done a lousy job explaining what I'm looking for, so if something is unclear, please ask and I'll clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to handle this would be to use an [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx), not a string format binding.

This would let you convert to and from text in any format you choose, but store the data in an integer.

Comment: Brilliant!  Not quite as easy as I had thought it might be, but this looks like it will do the job for me splendidly.  Thank you for the recommendation.  I'm going to leave the question out there a few more moments, but if no simpler solution presents itself, I'll mark yours.

Comment: @MattB Given that you're changing the value, this is the idiomatic way to do it.  The other alternative would be to just do the conversion to a decimal in the VM layer (ie: have a second property for the decimal value you used for binding)

Comment: There are quite a few fields that are similar to this one in my app - in this case I think using an IValueConverter might be less work than creating a decimal property for each of the values I'm looking at - but I'll double check to be sure.  My brain must be a little fried, I should have thought of that second option myself.

Comment: @MattB I prefer `IValueConverter` if it's going to exist in more than one place - since it lets you build the logic once, and you get guaranteed consistency

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged both C# and VB, my solution is a C# solution. Assuming the user can only go up to 2 demcimal points:

```
 String toInteger = Regex.Replace(TextBox.Text,"[$]|[.]","");
 // You can cast the toInteher to int value if you want like:
 // Convert.ToInt32(toInteger);
 String toValue = "$" + toInteger.Substring(0, toInteger.Lenght-2) + "." + toInteger.Substring(toInteger.Lenght-2, 2);
```

Comment: I actually write primarily in VB, just our shop thing, but I understand the C# just fine - I have to translate C# to VB constantly.  Kind of an odd position to be in.  Anyway, if I go with the second property method rather than IValueConverter, I'll give this a shot.